# Function to get pair of numbers in a given list of numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, sorting

I am writing a function that tries to return an integer representing the number of matching pairs of numbers in a given list. Below is the code.

```
def testfunc(n, ar):
    count = []
    ar.sort()
    print(ar)
    if len(ar) == n:
        for i in range(len(ar)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(ar)):
                if ar[i] == ar[j]:
                    count.append(1)
                    if ar[i+1] == ar[j+1]:
                        count.append(1)
                        break
    return len(count)
```

It works when the input is like below, test case 1 but fails when it is test case 2.

test case 1:

```
n = 9
ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
```

test case 2:

```
n = 10
ar = [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Please advice what mistake am I doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count the number of occurances of each item in the list, getting a mapping of items to counts, the number of matching pairs of an item is the count of that item divided by 2 rounded down.  We can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the items, and floor division `//` to get the number of matching pairs of each item.

```
from collections import Counter

def testfunc(arr):
    return sum(v//2 for v in Counter(arr).values())

print(testfunc([10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20])) # 3
print(testfunc([1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]))       # 4
print(testfunc([2,2,3,3,5,8,5,9,8]))                  # 4
```

There's no need to pass the length of the list because you can always get the length of a list by calling `len(arr)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but the question demands passing n, which is the number of items in the list also as an argument into the testfunc. So it must always be testfunc(n,ar). where ar is the array name.

Comment: You can easily modify the above function to take `n` and then  not do anything with it.

Comment: :) Yeah. Got it. Your method has a smaller code footprint. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

your going over the array length in

```
if arg[i+1] == arg[j+1]:
```

try this, it should work for both cases.

```
def testfunc(ar):
    ar.sort();
    count = i = 0
    while i + count < len(ar) - 1:
        if ar[count + i] == ar[count + i + 1]:
            count += 1
        i += 1
    return count
```

Comment: The function must have two arguments. n is the number of items in the array and ar is the array itself. The input will have both these coming in from the user.

Comment: I tried your script on testfunc(9, [2,2,3,3,5,8,5,9,8]). But the output shows 2. Where as the output must be 4.

Comment: I have edited your scripted by adding ar.sort() at the beginning of the function. Now it works perfectly. Thank you for your answer.